# regext to remove specific style tag from string

Tags: php, regex

here is my string , i want to remove the style tag with `yasrcss-inline-css` id  and its content

```
$text = "abc
<style id='yasrcss-inline-css' type='text/css'>

        .rateit .rateit-range {
            background: url(https://www.newseo.ir/wp-content/plugins/yet-another-stars-rating/img/star.png) left 0px !important;
        }

        .rateit .rateit-hover {
            background: url(https://www.newseo.ir/wp-content/plugins/yet-another-stars-rating/img/star.png) left -21px !important;
        }

        .rateit .rateit-selected {
            background: url(https://www.newseo.ir/wp-content/plugins/yet-another-stars-rating/img/star.png) left -42px !important;
        }

        div.medium .rateit-range {
            /*White*/
            background: url(https://www.newseo.ir/wp-content/plugins/yet-another-stars-rating/img/stars24.png) left 0px !important;
        }

        div.medium .rateit-hover {
            /*Red*/
            background: url(https://www.newseo.ir/wp-content/plugins/yet-another-stars-rating/img/stars24.png) left -29px !important;
        }

        div.medium .rateit-selected {
            /*Yellow*/
            background: url(https://www.newseo.ir/wp-content/plugins/yet-another-stars-rating/img/stars24.png) left -58px !important;
        }

        /* Creating set 32 */

        div.bigstars .rateit-range {
            /*White*/
            background: url(https://www.newseo.ir/wp-content/plugins/yet-another-stars-rating/img/stars32.png) left 0px !important;
        }

        div.bigstars .rateit-hover{
            /*red*/
            background: url(https://www.newseo.ir/wp-content/plugins/yet-another-stars-rating/img/stars32.png) left -37px !important;
        }

        div.bigstars .rateit-selected
        {
            /*Gold*/
            background: url(https://www.newseo.ir/wp-content/plugins/yet-another-stars-rating/img/stars32.png) left -74px !important;
        }


</style>
";
```

here my regex

```
echo preg_replace("/<style id='yasrcss-inline-css' type='text\/css'>(.*?)<\/style>/", " ", $text);
```

but it doesn't work , am i missing something ?

Comment: you may need to use the `/m` modifier on your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
(<style id='yasrcss-inline-css') (.|\n)*?(</style>)
```

Tested [here](http://regexr.com/3tufn)

Comment: i did much the same, but i used `([\s\S]*?)` realistically as long as it works.

Comment: thanx , any idea why this wont work ? 
`$text = "<style type='text/css'> a </style>";
echo preg_replace("/(<style type='text\/css') (.|\n)*(<\/style>)/", " ", $text);`

Comment: @hretic you're missing the `>` after `'text\/css'` ;)

Comment: thanx , i didnt put `>` bcuz you didnt put it on your answer and that regex worked